# Failed to send email: Index was outside the bounds of the array By Power Shell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

send HTML email to specified recipients in SQL server using PowerShell. Rec error Failed to send an email: Index was outside the bounds of the array By Power Shell. We are selecting data from SQL table. the index is outside the bounds.

What will be the solution

```
 $reader = $sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

$html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>"
$html += "<div style=""font-family:'Segoe UI', Calibri, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 14px; max-width: 768px;"">"
$html += "Welcome {firstname}  Access the</br> </br>"
$html += "Please note that your username and password are case sensitive."
$html +="<table style='border-spacing: 0px; border-style: solid; border-color: #ccc; border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;'>"

while ($reader.Read()) {
    $username = $reader.GetString(1)
    $firstname = $reader.GetString(2)
    $profilepropertyvalue = $reader.GetString(3)
    $lastname = $reader.GetString(4)

    $html += "<tr>"
    $html += "<td style='padding: 10px; border-style: solid; border-color: #ccc; border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;'>{0}</td>" -f $username
    $html += "<td style='padding: 10px; border-style: solid; border-color: #ccc; border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;'>{0}</td>" -f $firstname
    $html += "<td style='padding: 10px; border-style: solid; border-color: #ccc; border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;'>{0}</td>" -f $profilepropertyvalue
    $html += "<td style='padding: 10px; border-style: solid; border-color: #ccc; border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;'>{0}</td>" -f $lastname
    $html += "</tr>"

}
```

Please give the solution. Using while loop.

Comment: Unrelated to the question but you might find [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-6.0) more useful and efficient for this use case than a `System.Array` (`@( )`)

Comment: There appears to be no attempt to use indexing (e.g. `[0]`) in your code. Please update your question to show the line that actually causes the error.

Comment: Send Email from PowerShell with SQL Server and Email Queue

Comment: is there any way that I could send you the full file?

Comment: You need to start with index 0, not 1, so go from `$username = $reader.GetString(0)` to `$lastname = $reader.GetString(3)`

Comment: Thanks Theo
 $mail = New-Object EASendMail.SmtpMail("TryIt")
    $mail.From.Address = $sender

    $recipient = New-Object EASendMail.MailAddress($firstname, $profilepropertyvalue)
    $mail.To.Add($recipient) > $null

    $mail.Subject = $subject
    if($htmlFormat) {
        $mail.HtmlBody = $body
    }
    else {
        $mail.TextBody = $body
    }

    # please change server, user, password to yours
    $server = New-Object EASendMail.SmtpServer("cosmtp01p.brandmuscle.local")
    $smtp = New-Object EASendMail.SmtpClient
    $smtp.SendMail($server, $mail)

Comment: Error is" Failed to send email: Cannot find type [EASendMail.SmtpMail]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded."

Comment: Did you install EASendMail first? Did you reference it in your script `[reflection.assembly]::LoadFile("Path\to\EASendMail.dll")` before trying to use it? See [Send Email from PowerShell - Tutorial](https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/powershell.aspx?cat=0#send-email-from-powershell-tutorial)